# Can I write some codes that runs even if the program forced to quit?

Tags: c#

Is there any ways to include codes which run even if the program forced to quit?

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    socket.Close();
    System.Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: By forced you mean killing it in the task manager?

Comment: yup, killing by the task manager or forced by exception.

Comment: I don't think so, but you can check previous unexpected shutdown.

Comment: You can hook unhandled exceptions.